# Problems with recompiling Swish++

Tags: software-installation, uninstall

I'm working with Swish++ in Ubuntu 12.04. Due to my thesis I must install Swish++ from the source code. During the installation I faced with several problems, but finally I solved them and Swish++ package was successfully installed.
Although I found a discrepancy with Swish++ names (I asked [this question,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425632/discrepancy-with-swish-names) but got no answers there). Anyway, despite this, everything went ok. I could use `index` and `search` with all the functions of `index++` and `search++`.

But now I have another problem. I changed config files of Swish++ and need to recompile it. The first time I did it I used command `make`. How can I delete Swish++ and install it again? The command `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove swish++` says that package hasn't been istalled and can't be removed.
How can I remove programms having been installed from the source code?

Answer (score 0):

I you still have the source directory where you built Swish++ for the first time you can uninstall it using the same Makefile with:

```
sudo make unistall
```

Comment: That also didn't work. There's no 'uninstall' command.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to install Swish++ from sources:

- First I downloaded the latest version here:
  `~/Downloads/swish++-6.1.5`
- From this directory I can successfully run `make uninstall`

If that doesn’t work for you this it all the steps that the uninstall command performed:

```
cd /usr/local/bin && rm -fr index search extract
cd /usr/local/lib && rm -fr WWW.pm
rm -fr /etc/init.d/searchd \
        /etc/rc1.d/K99searchd \
        /etc/rc2.d/K99searchd \
        /etc/rc3.d/S99searchd \ 
        /etc/rc5.d/S99searchd \
        /etc/rc6.d/K99searchd
cd /usr/local/man/man1 && rm -fr extract.1 httpindex.1 index.1 search.1 splitmail.1
cd /usr/local/man/man3 && rm -fr WWW.3
cd /usr/local/man/man4 && rm -fr swish++.conf.4 swish++.index.4
cd /usr/local/man/man8 && rm -fr searchd.8 searchmonitor.8
```

run them individually with `sudo` to get root privileges.